# Could not display "x-nautilus-desktop:///

Tags: installation, nautilus, inspiron

I am receiving this error after a new install of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to a Dell Inspiron 9300.  Any ideas why?  Having trouble finding any answers by searching.

Answer (score 1):

I probably faced the very same problem which said something like:

```
Dbus error....could not display x=nautilus-desktop
 .../usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd not succeeded...
```

This was resolved by running `sudo apt-get update` and then upgrading / reinstalling the packages `gvfs` and `fuse`and its dependencies if any.

That's it.

In my case, I doubt if the 64bit Linux Mint ISO, I ran in live mode directly from the HDD which caused the problem in the first place. May be those partitions which were mounted during the live mode were not properly unmounted.

Actually I came across this post of yours yesterday while searching for a solution, but could not find a satisfactory solution anywhere on the web. Fortunately what I tried worked... posting it here so it could be easy reference for anybody in future.